# Word 2016 - Can't save to AFP share (El Capitan)

Tags: network, ms-office, afp

One of our macs running El Capitan mysteriously can't save Word 2016 documents to our AFP share anymore.

More specifically, when trying to save a Word 2016 document to our AFP share, the normal "Save" dialog pops up. After completing the dialog, Word dutifully closes it and then displays a "Save as..." dialog a short time later (with the file not having been saved to the share). Subsequent attempts to save via the "Save as..." dialog yield the same behavior.

This is exceedingly weird, as:

- Other Office programs (Excel, etc.) on that very machine don't make any trouble when trying to save to the share.
- The affected machine can use the share just fine otherwise (e.g. Finder).
- Other users have no trouble saving to the share from Word 2016.

I updated Office without any luck. Then I reinstalled it, still no luck.
Finally, i mounted the share via SMB... no dice.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles over this:

It turned out that Word had saved state to a '.TemporaryItems' folder right at the root of the share.

Apparently its contents were corrupted, causing the described problem.

Deleting the folder resolved the issue.